# WinForms.DataGridView VirtualMode Collapsing rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, virtualmode

I am working on a WinForms Application, that have a DataGridView, this Control emulates a TreeView, so the RowCount changes drastically. I am having a performance issue when collapsing rows...

### Example:

```
// dataGrid.VirtualMode = true;
// dataGrid.RowCount = 100.000;
dataGrid.RowCount = 2; // Is too Slow!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you using `VirtualMode`, it is usually much faster to do like this:

```
dataGrid.Rows.Clear();
dataGrid.RowCount = 2;
```